# Struts2 String value in no-arg constructor is changed to an empty string

Tags: java, struts2

I have the following java object.

```
public class TestClass {
private String testString;
private int testInt;

public TestClass(){
    this.testInt = 1;
    this.testString = "test";
}
... getters and setters
```

I have included the following `Struts2` `textfields` in my `jsp` page.

```
        <s:textfield name="test.testString" />
        <s:textfield name="test.testInt" />
```

I am not initializing the `test` object in my code and am relying on `Struts2` using the `no-arg` constructor.  `Struts2` is overwriting the `testString` field with an empty `String` after the `no-arg` constructor puts the `String` "test" in the field but the `1` in the `testInt` field displays.  Why does this happen?

Comment: see if making the variables public instead of private shows the "test" text..? accessing the values with the dot operator when the variables are private to that class shouldn't work but then again i don' know much about Struts. You could also try using the getters instead of the dot operator. As for why the int works and the string doesn't I have no clue.

Comment: I have public getters and setters for the two fields which is what Struts expects.  After looking at it some more I think Struts is treating no input value as an empty string and overwriting the value.  I'm not sure why it doesn't do the same for the int field.

Comment: it's interesting they expect those getters but then refer to using the dot operator. that's strange to me. can you try  <s:textfield name="test.getString()" /> ? or would that not work

Comment: The getters and setters are working.  I can see the "test" value get replaced in my debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is when the form is submitted, `Struts2` converts the empty `test.testString` field into an empty string and puts it in the Java field.  Evidently `Struts2` does not convert an empty `int` field into a 0.